# DNS Nameserver change

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to change the nameservers for a particular domain.

I control the DNS server that is currently set as the nameserver for the domain in question. This server is also listed in the SOA.

I want to move the DNS to Amazon Route53, I have created duplicate records for the zone there.

My question is, what will happen if I change the nameserver entries (to point to Route53) on the current DNS server?

Will the whole internet be updated with the new nameserver values and everybody rejoice in happiness? Or... will nothing happen - i.e. does the nameserver change need to occur at a higher level; i.e. done by the current registrar?

Or will something even worse happen?

p.s. I am a developer that is playing with forces that are beyond his comprehension, please go easy on me

Comment: Thanks for the downvote - it would be great if you could add a comment to explain why so that I can improve my questions in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the name servers needs to be done at the registrar, not at the current name servers.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty is this still the case even though the DNS server that I have access to is listed in the SOA record?

Comment: Yes. The NS and SOA records only designate what host (server) is reponsible for the zone. That host has to be resolveable to an ip address, which is what the A (host) record is for.

Comment: Glad to help...